# Is there a directional aspect to Beta decay dependant on nucleus orientation

Tags: nuclear-physics

Does beta decay occur in certain directions relative to a nucleus orientation?

Would the nucleus geometry or spin direction have an impact?

This effect could may be tested if a radioactive nucleus with spin is oriented in a magnetic field or is under NMR.

Have such tests been performed or has this effect been seen in other tests in which the orientation may be fixed due to magnetic effects in particle accelerators or magnetic alignment in crystals for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example would be 'Nuclear Magnetic Resonance of F$^{20}$ by Polarized Neutron Capture and $\beta$-Decay Anisotropy, TUng Tsang and Donald Connor, [Physical Review](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.132.1141) 132(3) 1141-1146 (1963). Briefly, they irradiated fluorine compounds with polarized neutrons to make the F$^{20}$ nuclei. The beta decay under NMR conditions (magnetic field + RF) then shows asymmetries of a few percent because of the polarization of the nuclei interacting with the field..

Comment: Thanks Jon. It's a good example and answers well my question. Do we know if electron capture can have similar anisotropy? I suppose this would be more difficult to measure but may be it would be visible as a change in rate under NMR?

Comment: @Stephen - an interesting question that I have no ready answer for. One might think that a spin-polarized electron beam interacting with a polarized nucleus might have some anisotropy... A recent conference paper (D. Dutta, AIP Conference Proceedings 1563, 219-222 (2013)) proposes to use a spin-polarized electron beam and the e+He3 -> H3+n reaction to measure the form factor of the He3 nucleus. Is that kind of what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks that is interesting I will take a look at it. I was originally thinking about electron capture of a k shell electron fro example from within the atom but this looks like it could be interesting too do you know if the electron beam in this reaction is bombarding the He3 nucleus or if it is disrupting the atom some how to cause k shell electron capture? Either way it'

Comment: I think the incident electron enters the nucleus, converts a proton to a neutron making H4, which then rapidly kicks the neutron out to leave H3 plus the neutron.

Comment: Thanks Jon, originally I was thinking about the effects of the nucleus structure and shape on the electron orbitals but it occurs to me that if spin is taken into account then this may also affect electron capture due to magnetic effects and dipolar attraction. I suppose this could be checked by having beams with opposite spin, or using other particle beams with different charge, spin and magnetic moment such as protons and neutrons, although I suppose these would be more disruptive. I suspect there are other papers out there that have also looked at this so I will do some digging.